# Python Real time Audio Visualizer but without the graphs

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pyaudio

**Edit I got my solution from 
https://www.swharden.com/wp/2016-07-19-realtime-audio-visualization-in-python/

```
import pyaudio
import numpy as np

CHUNK = 4096 # number of data points to read at a time
RATE = 44100 # time resolution of the recording device (Hz)

p=pyaudio.PyAudio() # start the PyAudio class
stream=p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,channels=1,rate=RATE,input=True,
          frames_per_buffer=CHUNK) #uses default input device

# create a numpy array holding a single read of audio data
for i in range(10): #to it a few times just to see
    data = np.fromstring(stream.read(CHUNK),dtype=np.int16)
    print(data)

# close the stream gracefully
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

I am interested in working on a project but I have no idea how to start. I have quite decent basic knowledge about Python 3. I want to make a script that will convert real time audio output into number values instead of the graph. I have did some research and found out that it can be done with pyAudio and numpy but I can't seem to find any docs or guides on how to convert the audio into numbers instead of graphs. What I want to do is like it will press a key on my keyboard (to toggle rgb) based on the audio "beat" or something like that. Long story short I want it to be able to flicker based on the music / audio.

Basically 
**I just need the tools and basic concept of how am I going to do it**

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Your question is quite vague. What is "the graph"? Is it an oscilloscope (single line), a spectrum view (bass/treble line plot), or a spectrogram (2D sliding bass/treble graph)? What kind of numbers do you want, what will be in RGB, and what will flicker?

Comment: @jimbo1qaz basically I wan to make a script that spams a key on my keyboard based on how fast the beat of the music/audio output is that's all

Comment: @WhiteRevolver you do not have to add SOLVED to your question, if you have solved your problem then I invite you to publish a solution and mark it as correct, that is the way to do it in SO.